# Создание и повторное использование собственного view в java для android

Tags: android, view, customview

Есть xml разметка которая должна многократно использоваться на одном экране приложения. Разметка содержит три textview. Как создать собственный view элемент из этой разметки, с возможностью задавать значения в любой textview?

Код разметки:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/parametr"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edizm"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Например так: `View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_name, null);` Устанавливать значение в любой текст вью:
        `((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parametr)).setText("Some Text");`

Comment: @eugeneek, спасибо, пиши как ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Инфлейтим вью из xml файла:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_name, null);
```

Устанавливать значение в любой текст вью:

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parametr)).setText("Some Text");
```